# Bug on create address on opc-order (Prestashop 1.5)

Tags: prestashop

On Prestashop 1.5 when I'm creating a customer on One page Checkout order

I put all data on delivery fields, allright.

When I need another address for invoice I was clicked checkbox.

If I miss some data of Invoice Address and I submit this Prestashop don't shows me an error with the data missed to fill, displays an ajax error "unable to save address", but the customer and the address was created!!!

How can I fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is providing enough information. You would need to tell us the errors on the page.

Please add define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', true);
in /config/defines.inc.php

That should tell you more information to work with.

You also can change preferences in Advanced Parameters > Performance

Also, check if this issue persists on all browsers.